# Connection between Kronecker pairing and duality of cohomology/homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In the **Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology** by **Davis & Kirk**, we consider the **Kronecker pairing** which is defined by

$$H^n(C;R) \times H_n(C;R) \to R \\ ([\varphi],[\alpha]) \mapsto \varphi(\alpha)$$

where $H^n(C;R)$ is the cohomology and $H_n(C;R)$ is the homology with coefficients over a ring $R$.

We know this defines a map $$H^n(C;R) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C;R),R) \\ [\varphi] \mapsto ([\alpha] \mapsto \varphi(\alpha)). $$

Davis & Kirk want to prove that cohomology is not the dual of homology in general and mentioned that The map $H^n(C;R) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C;R),R)$ does not need to be injective nor surjective.

***My question***: Why is it enough to consider this specific map?

If cohomology is the dual of homology, then $H^n(C;R) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C;R),R)$. So why can't there be another bijective map $H^n(C;R) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C;R),R)$ then?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That the map under consider is an isomorphism is the definition of duality. Not simply that the two modules are isomorphic.

Comment: This map is always surjective. See hatcher's universal coefficient theorem for a discussion (he calls this map "h"). Failure of injectivity is exactly what Ext measures.

Comment: @Paul T don't we need to add that the complex is free to have surjectivity?

Answer (score 3):

> ***My question***: Why is it enough to consider this specific map?

There doesn't seem to be an immediate reason, although it could be true.

What I think the authors had in mind is that from an intuitive point of view, this map is the only natural map to look at. In a sense, if that map fails to be an isomorphism, then the existence or non-existence of *another* one that would be an isomorphism is not so interesting, because it would probably lack "good" properties.

However, their example (of the real projective plane) goes further and *actually* shows that homology and cohomology don't have to be dual.

Answer (score 0):

The idea for this map comes from the universal coefficient theorem for cohomology.
That map is surjective and its kernel is $Ext^1(H_{n-1}(C),R)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem